# Progress bar on copying files to USB

Tags: usb, nautilus, filemanager, cache

On the Nautilus file manager, when copying any file to a flash drive, the progress bar will immediately go to 100%, signifying the transfer has completed. The issue is that the files have only been written to cache, and are still being transferred from cache to disk.

Is there any way to make Nautilus 'cache aware' so it would only show progress of data actually copied to the drive?
Failing that, is there any way to reduce the write cache of USB devices ONLY to around ~5MB so that the progress bar will actually do its job?

Currently on Ubuntu 20.04 with 16GB RAM

Edit: I'm not looking to completely disable cache, nor do I want to manually adjust mount options for each device.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch off caching for usb device when writing to it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5051/how-to-switch-off-caching-for-usb-device-when-writing-to-it)

Comment: Not really, I don't want to completely disable cache, I especially don't want to have to manually set mount options for each USB device that I plug in. There must be a way to explicitly set the size of the cache, rather than have it depend on the amount of RAM.

Comment: This is no progress bar, but it will give you a more accurate feedback on the writing process, let it be internal disk or other media: https://askubuntu.com/a/1306383/1157519 You will clearly see when a write process is complete.

Comment: Thanks Levente, the system monitor extension would be very useful to infer if data transfer is complete or not, and is available at a glance!

Comment: Yes, that's what it provides. When hovered by the mouse cursor, it also tells you the transfer rate.

Answer (score 0):

as I can't comment, still for being a beginner (low reputation), so I'll answer here.

this question seems duplicated,

see:

- [Disable Nautilus caching mechanism](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151283/disable-nautilus-caching-mechanism)
- [How to switch off caching for usb device when writing to it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5051/how-to-switch-off-caching-for-usb-device-when-writing-to-it)

Other alternative, you can try, by command line:

see and install : https://github.com/Xfennec/progress

```
cp bigfile newfile & progress -mp $!
```

Comment: Thanks Candido. Unfortunately none of those threads solve my problem. Progress is a nice tool, it doesn't seem to pick up any file transfers on my system and I wouldn't want to have to manually invoke a terminal session to monitor file transfer in any case.